Getting the Index of the elements from an array that when substracted to the elements with same index from another array is negatif
As indicated in the question (maybe not properly formulated) I am trying to get the index of an array for which the difference between each of its element and the index-corresponding element of the second array is < 0. Maybe the code below will explain more what I am trying to obtain. I succeded to get the desired indexes using flatMap() function but could not get it using the filter() function which I think is more appropriate in this case (always getting here the element but not the index)


let array1 = ['524', '587', '034', '816', '65', '7']
let array2 = ['3', '0', '33', '4', '193', '13']



function getSumOfArrays(array1, array2){
    let sumArray = array1.map((elem,idx)=>parseFloat(elem) - parseFloat(array2[idx]))
    return sumArray
}

function getIdxNegativeDiff1(array1, array2){   //this function works   
    let negatifIdx1 = array1.flatMap((elem,idx)=>{return parseFloat(elem)-parseFloat(array2[idx]) < 0 ? idx : [] })
    return negatifIdx1
}

function getIdxNegativeDiff2(array1, array2){          
    let negatifIdx2 = array1.filter((elem,idx)=>{ return (parseFloat(elem)-parseFloat(array2[idx]) < 0 ? idx : '')})
    return negatifIdx2
}



console.log(array1)
console.log(array2)
console.log(getSumOfArrays(array1, array2))
console.log(getIdxNegativeDiff1(array1, array2))
console.log(getIdxNegativeDiff2(array1, array2))



Tried many possibilities but could not reach the solution with filter. Could someone with the solution

Based on your examples, what is your desired result?

@mykaf I would like to get it working using filter() function

You haven't actually defined "get it working"; what's the desired result? What value(s) should we get?

filter() will return the the array's value for each element that your callback returns something truthy.

getting the index of the elements (both arrays are always same length. I am making a snippet to make it clearer

Sorry, getting the index of which elements, exactly? Where the difference is negative? Do you want the index from the original array(s)?

So I need to get [4,5] not [65,7] which correspond to the index of elements that shows (65-193) and (7-13) both results are <0

Yes from original arrays

You're really close! getIdxNegativeDiff2() is filtering the differences that are <0, you just  need to find the indices of those values in the original array(s), and you can do that with Array.map():


let array1 = ['524', '587', '034', '816', '65', '7']
let array2 = ['3', '0', '33', '4', '193', '13']


function getIdxNegativeDiff2(array1, array2){          
    let negatifIdx2 = array1.filter(
        (elem,idx)=>{ 
        return (parseFloat(elem)-parseFloat(array2[idx]) < 0 ? idx : '')
      }
    ).map(el => array1.indexOf(el)) 
    return negatifIdx2
}

console.log("array1",array1)
console.log("array2",array2)

console.log("getIdxNegativeDiff2",getIdxNegativeDiff2(array1, array2))




This solution is working and you added .map after filter, but Can't we just do it with filter only?

I don't think so, since filter() always returns the matching values from the array you call it on. We are working with two sets of data: the differences and the indices, with one driving the other. If you were to start with an array of indices, you'd have to have mapped it already, so either way, you are filtering and mapping.

Yes good point. But why I am thinking we might do it it is because we could still use idx from array1 that we called on filter() function. However still the conditional operator I used with filter did not return idx

The callback in Array.filter returns a boolean, which determines whether or not to keep the current array value. Any idx > 0 would be truthy and thus would return true and keep that array element.

You can use the index in your filter callback, but it'll never return the index.

Yes exactly I think so now, I was mislead because we can however return the elem. Good point again. Another solution I found is this  function getIdxNegativeDiff2(array1, array2){        let a = []          let negatifIdx2 = array1.filter((elem,idx)=>{ return (parseFloat(elem)-parseFloat(array2[idx]) < 0 ? a.push(idx) : '')})     return a }

In that case, if you weren't actually going to use the array returned from filter(), you might as well just use a forEach() loop or a regular for-loop.

Don't return the index from the filter callback. That will return 0 if the condition is true for the first element, but 0 is falsey. Just return the result of the comparison, don't use a ternary.
